# Content-disposition: Japanese file name is garbled

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, url-encoding, content-disposition

I try to export a content of a JSP page (the content is in **Japanese**) and I want to give to exported file also a Japanese name. But I get the “Save dialog” with a garbled file name - I don't see correct Japanese.

[image]

This dialog is called by this line in the JSP file:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName+".xml\"");
```

*filename* is encoded in UTF-8 by using java.net.URLEncoder.

It works for IE browser from version 9 (shows the correct name).

But in IE 8  the behavior is very strange: it works on some computers and on some computers it doesn’t work. It always work on IE 8 with XP but with Win7 it doesn’t work on most computers.
I tried to reset browser, clear browser cache.

Another point: if I change the language for non – Unicode programs in Windows to Japanese it also works.

I use Tomcat app server.

What can I do? I've seen a lot of posts related to this but always it's described as encoding issue. And here I understand that encoding is good because it works in many other versions of IE.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a reliable way to get this to work pre-IE9. For IE9 and above, just use the header field as defined in the specification. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/ (test cases) and http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html (specification).

Comment: They suggest to use "filename*" (with star) for non-ascii symbols but unfortunately the "filename*" attribute doesn't work in IE8 as I understand...

Comment: Yes. Just forget about IE < 9.

Answer (score 0):

You try the following code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+new String(fileName.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1")+".xml\"");
```